# Sharepoint 2013 search no result anonymous user use term with double quotes

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, bdc

I am using SharePoint 2013 search that The content come from an external content source -via BDC connectivity -using  Hebrew text.
My problem start when the anonymous  user search text with double qoutes (")
Example:
(מד"א)
but when he use ('') or escapte the double qoutes ("/")  he will get all the result.
Example:
(מד''א)

after awhile I notice that things work fine when I test it on a single server(both anonymous and authenticated user )

Answer (score 0):

I feel sheepish - basically the .bdcm file was not updated in the different environments.

**I need to add a comment might help somebody someday:**
The original problem occurred when you using Hebrew with bdc and you get no result when searching a term that include "doublequote".
The Solution was given by microsoft:
you need to add a column Title with "אבגדהוזחטיכלמםנן" and SharePoint  ץ